# How to change the password of a user on HP-UX server that can access the options as arguments

Tags: command, hp-ux

Good day!

I have a trouble when I want to change the password of a user on HP-UX server.
I used:

```
Server:/home/testoo#sudo /bin/passwd arun  
Changing password for arun  
Last successful password change for arun: NEVER  
Last unsuccessful password change for arun: NEVER  

Do you want (choose one letter only):  
        pronounceable passwords generated for you (g)  
        a string of letters generated (l) ?  
        to pick your passwords (p) ?  

Enter choice here: p  
New password:  
Re-enter new password:  
Passwd successfully changed
```

It's Ok. But now I want to change password on a command line with the above options are passed as argument.
for example:

```
passwd username --password PASSWD ...
```

Do you have any suggestion for me? please help me in this case.

Thank you in advance.